# register dll in mvc razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In web forms we can write this code above the page:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="xxx.CaptchaGenerator" 
Namespace="xxx.CaptchaGenerator" TagPrefix="mycaptcha" %>
```

Then it can be used:

```
<mycaptcha:CaptchaControl ID="ccJoin" 
runat="server" CaptchaHeight="31" CaptchaLength="5" />
```

How can I do this in mvc3, razor? I use this syntax `@Using xxx.CaptchaGenerator` and add this lines in my web config :

```
<pages>
  <namespaces>

    <add namespace="xxx.CaptchaGenerator"  />

    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

but it did not work.

Comment: When writing questions, please check the preview before posting. Any html tags must be marked as code or they will not show up in the post.

Answer (score 1):

You could add namespaces to the `~/Views/web.config`, not `~/web.config`. For example:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />

        <add namespace="xxx.CaptchaGenerator"  />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: in question exist TagPrefix property and use it but in this answer not exist it.
How do access to CaptchaGenerator in view?

Comment: @Mohsen, I don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

as i know cant use the server control in view(razorengine)..
you can use aspx file and then call it in your parent view with html.partial(aspx fileName)
i know this not a good solution and maybe not correct answer but its useful dear mohsen
شاید راه دیگه ایم باشه